# I cannot pass "side-panel content" to the side panel on the main menu page

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, vue.js, html-framework-7

I want My left and right Panel to be passed to the main menu page (dashboard), but it cannot work because what must be declare is the first page and in my case the first page (/ root) is login, if I pass it to root it worked, how to pass it to the dashboard without change the root page as a login

```
<!-- Left Panel -->
<f7-panel left reveal theme-dark>
  <f7-view url="/panel-left/"></f7-view>
</f7-panel>

<!-- Right Panel -->
<f7-panel right cover theme-dark>
  <f7-view url="/panel-right/"></f7-view>
</f7-panel>

<!-- Main View -->
<f7-view id="main-view" url="/" main :pushState="true"></f7-view>
```

Main View is set as login

The side panel object on dashboard (Menu page)

```
  <f7-nav-left>
    <f7-link icon-if-ios="f7:menu" icon-if-md="material:menu" panel-open=left/></f7-link>
  </f7-nav-left>
  <f7-nav-title>Graylite1</f7-nav-title>
  <f7-nav-right>
    <f7-link icon-if-ios="f7:menu" icon-if-md="material:menu" panel-open="right"></f7-link>
  </f7-nav-right>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tries this too But this was giving me the same problem too... so what I did was set it on index page which is login page in your case and disable every possible was of opening it... display none the 3bar icon in navbar and even set swipe open to false so no one can open it on login page and rest you can appen data after login using framework 7 js...

> I am using framework 7 core in that I disabled swipe panel open using
>   ...

```
  if(//check if user is logged in){
     app.panel.enableSwipe('right');
     $$(".panel-img").attr('src','//img src comes from api');
  }else{
    app.panel.disableSwipe('right');
  }
```

Worked For me May be this helps you too